# Book - Boy transported to the Himalayas by a book, undergoes an ordeal

Tags: story-identification, books

While I was in school I read many books. To the point that I can't remember the titles to most of them. Recently I decided to try to find some of them, but from what I can remember, I can't seem to find this one in particular.

It's about a boy or young man that receives a book or pamphlet of some kind and gets transported into the Himalayas or somewhere else rather cold where he undergoes an ordeal alongside a young woman that I believe has a scar or birthmark prevalent on her body. During the story I think they may have been fighting in a revolution or war and they end up in love. The story ends with the boy being transported home and changed somehow.

I read this in New York State several years ago and it was printed in English. I apologize for being unable to provide the exact year, but I'm lucky if I remember if a week has passed or a month. It can't have been any more than five years ago.

I apologize if this isn't enough information to find it, but I'm hoping someone else knows of it.

Comment: What year did you read it? (we don't know when you were in school). Might it have been published around then or did it feel older, what country were you in and what language was it written in? Can you remember anything about the books cover or any part of the authors name? Thanks, the more you help us the more we can help you :)

Comment: It strangely sounds like *The First Two Lives of Lukas Kasha* mixed up with  *The Westmark Trilogy*, both by Lloyd Alexander. But it's probably actually a third thing entirely.